# Setting up inbound custom email

Tags: email, email-server

I have recently set up a custom email address with a [well-known API infrastructure provider](http://www.3scale.net). Having never done this before I imagined the address would cover both outbound and inbound email. Although the outbound is working fine I now realize I have to set up the inbound myself. But I'm not sure what to do...

The email address is of the form 'support@example.com' I set it up according the instructions [here](https://support.3scale.net/howtos/basics/setup-custom-email). My main site is with GoDaddy, and I used the DNS manager to set up the various records. We already have internal Gmail, and there are MX records for @ pointing to Gmail servers. So do I have to add any new MX records? And if so pointing to where?

A bit lost and grateful for any help. :)

Comment: Why do I keep seeing people refer to "custom" email addresses and "custom" domains. There are no such things as "custom" email addresses or "custom" domains. There are email addresses and there are domains.

Comment: I see. They're stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The MX records for example.com need to point to email servers that are able to receive mail for support@example.com.

Are you saying that you have Google Apps with Gmail hosting example.com? If that is the case, your MX records for example.com should already be pointing at those servers, so just make sure you have a mailbox set up for support@example.com

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. Yes, we have Google Apps Gmail, so everyone on the project has a gmail account of the form person@example.com. There are 5 MX records for @ of the form ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM, etc.

Comment: So indeed I guess it's just a case of adding a new mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Email routing" configuration for a specific user in your Google Apps control panel, you can also specify that an existing user receive email for another email address (if you don't want to create a new user).